# How to search for website contains some keywords in its main domain?

Tags: google-search, search, search-engine

I remember a website whose URL contains a specific word ("Hamilton", in my case) but I don't remember exactly the URL. I have tried google it with the keyword's syntax `"Hamilton" feature of page` but don't success.

I have tried to use to `site:` operator but it only "get results from certain sites or domains" that I know; `related:` is better, but not all results have the *hamilton* in its URL (see [operations for Google Search](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en)). I also have tried using WhoIs or GoDaddy but they only show whether that domain is taken or not.

How do I search for website contains some keywords in its main domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the operator you are looking for is [inurl:](http://www.googleguide.com/advanced_operators_reference.html#inurl) (e.g. https://www.google.com/search?q=inurl:hamilton) which will search for keywords in the url. Hopefully you can use this along with some keywords to find the site you are after.

Comment: wow, how did you find this site? This should be included in the official the Google Support, right? Also, do you know how to search which URL only have it in the **main** domain?