# Possible to search for URLs containing a substring on Google Search?

Tags: google-search

Is it possible to search for URLs containing a substring, for example I'd like to find all URLs that have the ".gov.sg" string in it.

E.g.:

```
silverscheme.gov.sg
```

Also, can I restrict all the URLs to domains or subdomains only, so:

```
silverscheme.gov.sg
```

But not

```
silverscheme.gov.sg/some/path
```

If this is not possible, are there other web apps or website that allow for this?

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to search for website contains some keywords in its main domain?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/75598/how-to-search-for-website-contains-some-keywords-in-its-main-domain)

Comment: Do you mean only the domain / host part of the URL? Looks like it, but you did not state this specifically. (The answers are quite different whether you mean only the domain or for example the path part of the URL, see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/components-of-a-url/)